# KendoUI Responsive Grid Not Showing Page Scrollbars

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

We are working on trying to implement the KendoUI responsive grid - http://youtu.be/JWEtMNstjyc?t=34m16s

Here's our code snippet in jsBin - http://jsbin.com/OZuJUGA/2

The idea is to have the page be responsive (and the grid to be mobile friendly) and be used by all kinds of devices.  When we setup the mobile app using "new kendo.mobile.Application", the scrollbars for the page go away and the only way to scroll down the page on the desktop browser is to click and drag the page as if you were using a finger on a mobile device.

We want the page scrollbars to remain but have the grid be responsive.  How can we achieve that?

Also, we found it odd that the row containing the grid must have its height set otherwise the content below the grid will overlay the grid.  This too does not happen until we setup the mobile app with "new kendo.mobile.Application".

Answer (score 0):

Heard back from KendoUI team and here is what they said - *"The Kendo UI Mobile Application is not designed to be used on desktop devices. In addition, the mobile views and panes are not designed to be used in a standard flowing page layout in between other content. I don't see any specific benefits, which the Kendo UI Mobile Application can bring you in this particular scenario. The Grid itself will be mobile-friendly if you set **mobile:true** in its configuration, there is no need to include a Mobile Application"*

Based on their feedback I updated my sample and it worked as expected - http://jsbin.com/UrUsuFU/1